# Blank Activity vs Empty Activity

Tags: android

Does anybody know why the blank activity in the latest version of Android Studio now includes two .xml files for each Activity? My instinct is to use Empty Activity and continue doing things "the old way" but I'm wondering what Android's "bigger picture" is with these changes? Is it wiser to develop any future applications using this new Blank Activity format? Thank you.

Comment: I think one of them uses a Fragment for the Activity content

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does anybody know why the blank activity in the latest version of Android Studio now includes two .xml files for each Activity?

For Android Studio 1.5, `content_main.xml` contains the core UI of the activity. `activity_main.xml` wraps that in a bunch of other stuff (e.g., `CoordinatorLayout`) to demonstrate a couple of particular UI elements (e.g., FAB). `activity_main` uses `<include>` to incorporate `content_main` by reference.

These templates change occasionally, and so if you are reading this in the future, your edition of the templates may differ substantially (and please stop reading Stack Overflow answers from your flying car, as that's a safety hazard).

> I'm wondering what Android's "bigger picture" is with these changes?

IMHO, you are seriously overstating the role of these templates. They are samples, nothing more.

> Is it wiser to develop any future applications using this new Blank Activity format?

It is wiser to not pay all that much attention to the templates. They are samples, nothing more. Developers should know what they want to build and how they want to build it. If one of the templates is close to what is desired, use it. Otherwise, skip the new-activity wizard entirely and just add the new activity yourself.

In cases where the new-activity logic is not directly avoidable (e.g., new-project wizard), either use "Empty Activity" (as it has the least stuff that you would need to delete) or find some other solution. For example, other than for experimenting with the new-project wizard itself, I never use it, and I make a few Android projects a week. Instead, I'll copy an existing project and adjust it to the new package name and stuff, then import it into Android Studio, as I find that less irritating than having to rip out template-generated gunk.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Also don't take the templates as gospel when it comes to design style - I used the 'Navigation Draw' template once which doesn't follow Material guidelines, so ditched it and started a 'empty' project. Not sure if this is rectified in the most latest version, just something to be conscious of.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @CommonsWare, but it turns out the flying cars are self driving, (piloting) which, as you can imagine, is a LOT less fun but also a lot more safe and also frees us up to read SO answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose **Blank Activity** then you will have the option of having the activity use a `Fragment`. Also, Android Studio will automatically create two layout files for the activity, three if you choose the Fragment option, and also a menu resource file.

If you choose **Empty Activity** then you get to choose whether or not you want Android Studio to generate a layout file for the activity. If you choose the layout file option Android Studio will create one layout file, as opposed to two layout files in case of *Blank Activity*, and no menu resource file. Also, the layout file is much simpler and does not contain things like: `Coordinator Layout`, `Floating Action Button`, etc., whereas the layout file for *Blank Activity* contains these items, assuming you are using the latest version of Android Studio.